# Using lambda and strftime on dates when there are null values (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, strftime

I'm trying to change the format of a datetime column in my Dataframe using lambda and strftime like below

```
df['Date Column'] = df['Date Column'].map(lambda x: x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
```

However, since I have null values in some of these fields, this is giving me an error. I cannot drop these null rows because I still need them for the data in the other columns. Is there a way around this error without dropping the nulls.

Perhaps something like

```
df['Date Column'].map(lambda x: x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') if x != null else "")
```

?

The method I've used is to drop the nulls, format the column, then merge it back onto the original dataset, but this seems like a very inefficient method.

Comment: "Perhaps something like...." That's what I was about to suggest. Did it work?

Comment: It does not sadly. I've tried different forms of it. .notnull(), != np.nan, != "NaT", != "NaN, but none of them have worked, so I'm wondering if the method is wrong

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be not checking for nan/nat (un)equality, but `.notnull()` should work and it does for me:

```
s = pd.date_range('2000-01-01', periods=5).to_series().reset_index(drop=True)
s[2] = None
s

0   2000-01-01
1   2000-01-02
2          NaT
3   2000-01-04
4   2000-01-05
dtype: datetime64[ns]

s.map(lambda x: x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') if pd.notnull(x) else '')

0    01/01/2000
1    01/02/2000
2              
3    01/04/2000
4    01/05/2000
dtype: object
```

This returns the same that the answers by @Alexander and @Batman but is more explicit. It may also be slightly slower for large series.

Alternatively you can use the `.dt` accesor. The null values will be formatted as `NaT`.

```
s.dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

0    01/01/2000
1    01/02/2000
2           NaT
3    01/04/2000
4    01/05/2000
dtype: object
```

Comment: `s.dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')` does not seem to work with `None` values, at least with pandas 1.1.5: `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`

Comment: My code still works for the specific problem stated in the OP: a "datetime column". You must have some different, maybe a series of dtype `object` with objects of mixed types. My answer does not address such scenario.

Comment: Indeed, this will work if the column is correctly set to a datetime dtype. If all columns are None, the column may be set to object and calling dt will result in a crash.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I'd just define a small function, and then use that.

```
def to_string(date):
    if date:
        string = date.strftime('%Y%m%d')
    else:
        string = ""

    return string
```

Then

```
df['Date Column'].map(to_string)
```

Otherwise

```
df['Date Column'].map(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y%m%d') if x else "")
```

Comment: Sorry. You hadn't answered when I started editing my answer.
I prefer the function definition because I think it's easier to read. Which is why I prefaced my answer with "personally". It occurred to me afterwards that they may prefer not to do it that way.

Comment: Both methods ended up giving me the same error I was getting about null values. Goyo's solution worked for me, so I will be marking that as answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use a conditional assignment (ternary).

```
df['Date Column'] = df['Date Column'].map(lambda x: x.strftime('%m/%d/%Y') if x else '')
```

Comment: For some reason this method is still giving me the same error I was getting about null values. Goyo's solution worked for me, so I will be marking that as answer

Comment: I guess it depends on what you mean by "null values in some of these fields" (None vs. NaT vs. NaN).  I assumed None, but using notnull() includes the other cases.  Sample data helps to create better solutions that fit your requirements.

Comment: Ah you're totally correct. It was NaT because it was in datetime format, I apologize about that.